# What was the coverage of the Yuegong-1 (Lunar Palace-1) experiment in terms of life-support?

Tags: life-support

The Yuegong-1 (Lunar Palace-1) experiment in China aimed at evaluating bio-regenerative life-support systems, and crew psychology.

Some [reports](https://www.space.com/40610-china-mock-moon-mission-lunar-palace-1-photos.html) explain:

> Liu Hong said the test marks the longest stay in a bioregenerative life support system, in which humans, animals, plants and micro-organisms co-exist in a closed environment, simulating a lunar base.

Reading more about the subject, it is not clear how far the experiment is going in terms of life-support. Food is clearly covered, but how about air and energy (electricity)?

This [press release](http://ev.buaa.edu.cn/info/1013/1584.htm) from the host university is short, and the few names lead to no publication:

> Oxygen, water and food are recycled within the BLSS, creating an Earth-like environment.

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuegong-1) now states, citing only news articles:

> With a crew of 3, 55% of the food consumed would be produced internally, the rest would be from stocks laid-in. The oxygen would be regenerated through the vegetation compartment. The water is recycled internally. The crew's waste was turned into fertilizer for the vegetation.

The ecosystem inside Yuegong-1 looks fantastic in terms of practical achievements. It would help future endeavours to know what was covered, and what was left out. Life on the Moon will need full-coverage.